# Error parsing single digit hour time: 3:00 AM

Tags: java, time, datetime-parsing, java-time

so I've been trying to convert string Hour from 12 Hour Format to 24 Hour format, the code goes like:

```
public String convertAM(String checkinCheckoutTime) {
String withoutAM = checkinCheckoutTime.replaceAll("AM", "").trim();
if (withoutAM.length() == 1 || withoutAM.length() == 2) {
  return LocalTime.parse(
      withoutAM + ":00 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US))
      .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
} else {
  return LocalTime.parse(
      checkinCheckoutTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US))
      .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
}
```

}

I got green in this test:

```
    @Test
  public void convertCheckinCheckoutTime12AMWithSpace() {
    String checkOutTime = "12 AM";
    String expectedCheckOutTime = "00:00";

    String result = this.service.convertAM(checkOutTime);

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedCheckOutTime, result);
  }
```

But in this test I get error:

```
    @Test
  public void convertCheckinCheckoutTimeAMNoRangeWithSpace() {
    String checkOutTime = "3 AM";
    String expectedCheckOutTime = "3:00";

    String result = this.service.convertAM(checkOutTime);

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedCheckOutTime, result);
  }
```

The error is:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '3:00 AM' could not be parsed at index 0
```

May I know what's wrong in 3 AM? Thank you in advance

Comment: replace `hh` by `h` in your formatter

Comment: Thank you, it works for single digit hour

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i need to change format for single or double digit hour, if 12 the format is hh:mm, if 3 the format is h:mm

Comment: No, it’s not necessary, and I would consider it over-complicating things. See the answers by Zabuza and myself.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

You are using the pattern `hh` for the hours. This demands two digit hours, e.g. `12` or `03`. But your input is a single digit, `3` for the hour field.

---

### Solution

Either adjust your inputs to be two digits, so `03` instead of `3`. Or use a pattern that is okay with a single digit, which would be just `h`.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> h, clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12), number, 12
>
> Number: If the count of letters is one, then the value is output using the minimum number of digits and without padding. Otherwise, the **count** of digits is used as the **width** of the output field, with the value **zero-padded** as necessary. The following pattern letters have constraints on the count of letters. Only one letter of 'c' and 'F' can be specified. Up to two letters of 'd', 'H', 'h', 'K', 'k', 'm', and 's' can be specified. Up to three letters of 'D' can be specified.

---

### Notes

You can simplify your code and reduce duplication by moving out the only part that is different, namely the input string. And since you return in your `if`, the `else` is unecessary. You can also simplify further and make the code more readable by splitting some of your nested statements and putting them into variables. You should also add a quick comment to explain what is going on:

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US);
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.US);

// Patch time without minutes, 3 AM to 3:00 AM
String withoutAM = checkinCheckoutTime.replaceAll("AM", "").trim();
boolean hasOnlyHours = withoutAM.length() == 1 || withoutAM.length() == 2;
String timeInput = hasOnlyHours ? withoutAM + ":00 AM" : checkinCheckoutTime;

return LocalTime.parse(timeInput, inputFormatter)
      .format(outputFormatter);
```

Note that your code will not work for inputs like `3 PM` since you only remove `AM`. You can simply add another call to also remove `PM` or put both into one regex, since you are using the regex-replace `replaceAll` instead of the non-regex `replace` anyways:

```
String withoutSuffix = checkinCheckoutTime.replaceAll("(AM|PM)", "").trim();
```

And the length check could be simplified to just `<= 2` (empty input would fail at parsing stage anyways).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Just use a format pattern string of `h[:mm] a`.

I wish you’d told us what your original time strings can look like. For this answer I am assuming:

- Hour within AM or PM can be 1 or 2 digits.
- Two-digit minute of the hour separated by colon may be present or absent.
- AM or PM separated by a space is always present.

All of this can be handled by one single format pattern string, so there is no need for you to modify the string before parsing it, and I find it simpler not to. The tricks are:

- One pattern letter `h` matches *one or two* digit hour, for example `3`, `03` and `12`.
- Square brackets enclose optional parts of the format. So `[:mm]` matches optional colon and minutes.

To see it in action:

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h[:mm] a", Locale.US);

    String[] timeStrings = {
            "3 AM", "12 AM", "3:00 AM", "3:40 AM", "12 PM", "12:20 PM", "4 PM", "04 PM"
    };
    for (String ts : timeStrings) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(ts, timeFormatter);
        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%-8s is parsed into %s%n", ts, time);
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> 3 AM     is parsed into 03:00
> 12 AM    is parsed into 00:00
> 3:00 AM  is parsed into 03:00
> 3:40 AM  is parsed into 03:40
> 12 PM    is parsed into 12:00
> 12:20 PM is parsed into 12:20
> 4 PM     is parsed into 16:00
> 04 PM    is parsed into 16:00
> ```

This said I am not comfortable with your whole approach. Situations where you should want to convert a time string in 12 hour format to a time string in 24 hour format are rare. As a rule you should keep your time in a `LocalTime` object, not in a string. On accepting an input string parse it into a `LocalTime` immediately. And only when you need to provide string output, format your `LocalTime` into a string.

Answer (score -1):

3 AM should be `03 AM`. You can update your code like this:

```java
...
if (withoutAM.length() == 1 || withoutAM.length() == 2) {
    if(withoutAM.length()==1){
        withoutAM = "0"+withoutAM;
    }
...
```

in `convertAM` function

Comment: Instead of manually adding a `0`, just adjust the pattern to also support single digit with `h` instead of `hh`.

Comment: oh yes... that is correct... I am updating my answer... and same output is achieved with my code...

Answer (score -1):

instead of sending 3 AM try to send 03 AM it will work fine. But while working with PM you should replace your method with this.

```
public static String convertAM(String checkinCheckoutTime) {
            String withoutAM = checkinCheckoutTime.replaceAll("AM", "").trim();
            String withoutPM = checkinCheckoutTime.replaceAll("PM", "").trim();
            System.out.println(withoutAM);
            System.out.println(withoutPM);
            if (withoutAM.length() == 1 || withoutAM.length() == 2) {
                System.out.println("length below 2");
                return LocalTime.parse(withoutAM + ":00 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US))
                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
            } else {
                System.out.println("lengh high");
                return LocalTime.parse(withoutPM + ":00 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US))
                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: This does not adress the issue with the single digit. It only gets rid of the AM/PM.